# Targus remote control as a teleop input?

Tags: teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to use a [targus amp13eu](http://targus.com/fr/product_details.asp?sku=AMP13EU) has a way to teleoperate my robot. Has anyone already done that or would know how to do?

Thanks a lot for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203097/targus-remote-control-as-a-teleop-input?/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any packages that specifically support this kind of device, but afaik, most *presentation devices* are actually just USB HID input devices (keyboards with just a few keys). I can imagine updating [teleop_twist_keyboard](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard) (or just remapping keys) would do the trick.

There are multiple ways under Linux to determine which particular keycodes / keys a device sends, see [Extra keyboard keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/extra_keyboard_keys#Keycodes) on the Arch wiki for some possible options.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2015-02-18**:
Thanks a lot, I'm gonna try this solution